# TFS - upload lnk file to test attachments

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to upload `lnk` file (shortcut for large `wmv` file that exists in network directory) to test attachments. The problem is whenever I download this file from TFS it has extension of `.download` instead of `.lnk` and I have to change the extension manually in order to watch the video.

Comment: A .DOWNLOAD file is a file that is currently being downloaded from the Internet or was stopped before the download finished. How big is the file in size?

Comment: 3kb, and it was in download format even after finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to your browser. I've tested in IE and Chrome, IE works while Chrome doesn't. You could try with IE.